# how to select a list item value from drop down value inside the table using selenium webdriver in .net

Tags: asp.net, selenium

I need a select a value "Name" in Search drop down field
 [shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/epwCT.jpg)

How to select a value name from dropdown?

Answer (score 1):

At the top of your file add `using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI;` This will provide the class `SelectElement`. Then you can use something like:

```
SelectElement searchBy = new SelectElement(driver.FindElement(By.Id("searchBy")));

// Use any of the following
searchBy.SelectByValue("Name");
searchBy.SelectByText("Name");
searchBy.SelectByIndex(1);
```

Comment: Hi Marcel, I tried with above code as well, It didn't worked for me. Below is the error .org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: #ddlSearch
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html

Comment: Can you provide some html or the webpage?

Answer (score 1):

First check whether is your element in frame or not if yes then switch to frame and then select a value from dropdown

if No then use SelectElement

```
SelectElement searchDropDown = new SelectElement(driver.FindElement("Locator may be ID/Css/xpath"));
```

after that use these methods

- SelectByValue: select value using value

  ```
  searchDropDown.SelectByValue("value");
  ```
- SelectByText: Select by visible text

  ```
  searchDropDown.SelectByText("value");
  ```
- SelectByIndex: Using Index

  ```
  searchDropDown.SelectByIndex(2);  // Index number or position
  ```

Comment: I tried but it didn't worked for me, org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: #ddlSearch   error is displaying

Comment: Without HTML or URL it is not possible to find root cause